# How to mount filesystem of Ubuntu Core

Tags: partitioning, mount, ubuntu-core

Today my instance of Ubuntu Core crashed completely, and it wont boot anymore. I do not have anything important on it, but [I've been strugglig for a while](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286535/crash-log-on-ubuntu-core) that the machine kept freezing and I had to do a hard reboot by unplugging the power.

To do some debugging it would be interesting to check the filesystem for logs. However, when I plug in the SD-card in my laptop, only the «system boot» partition shows up. The filesystem for storage shows up as «unknown» in Gparted, and it's not any options to mount it.

Anyone knows how I can mount the other filesystem?

Comment: Pulling out the power lead on a Raspberry Pi is likely to corrupt the SD card which is what appears to have happened. The problems you’ve been having could well be early signs of the card failing so I suggest you try a new card. It’s probably not worth trying to diagnose the logs if this is the case.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're correct. I guess it's the encryption of the Ubuntu Core filesystem that makes the partition unavailable.

Comment: If it’s encrypted then you have to unlock it first. To do that you will need the passphrase. I don’t know how you do that manually

Comment: Yeah, thats why I'm asking if anyone knows how to do it on Ubuntu ***Core***

Comment: You might need to edit your question to make it clear that you need help mounting an encrypted filesystem. Do you have a passphrase? Ubuntu core is designed for security so without a passphrase I doubt it’s possible

Comment: No passphrase. Just a normal Ubuntu Core installation of the RPi release.